# DateTime.Month.ToString("MMM") isn't working

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application

I am grabbing a date from SQL:

```
2009-10-28 11:17:06.690
```

I put this into a DateTime and fill it with the value from SQL:

```
DateTime createdDate;
createdDate = reader.GetDateTime(1);
```

I then want to write out the month so I do:

```
var fileMonth = createdDate.Month.ToString("MMM");
```

At this point in the code fileMonth is now = to "MMM" and not "Oct".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For future reference have a gander here when havin issues with custom date and time formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier

Comment: @Slump Thanks I will favorite this and remember that.

Answer (score 10):

The `.Month` property is just an integer, which knows nothing of DateTime formats. All you need is this:

```
var fileMonth = createdDate.ToString("MMM");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need:

```
var fileMonth = createdDate.ToString("MMM");
```

The `Month` property returns an integer between 1 and 12

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx

Comment: @JamesWilson Since you call `ToString` on an `int`, your `"MMM"` is really a [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), and here for "All other characters",
"The character is copied to the result string unchanged."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var fileMonth = createdDate.Month.ToString("MMM");
```

you should use:

```
var fileMonth = createdDate.ToString("MMM");
```

So, supppress the (.Month).

Answer (score -6):

I do like this:

```
            if (date.Month == 10)
            {
                string OCTOBERSTRING = "Oct";
            }
```

It work

Comment: Yes this would work, but it would produce a lot of extra code.

Comment: This actually *won't* work, if your language/culture settings have other names for the month.